# Connect router to modem to use it's hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, nat, modem, adsl

I have an ADSL modem that have problem with WIFI (wifi broken) , (i just use it with LAN).

And i also have a router modem (not adsl modem), how can i transmit network connection from my first modem to the router to use router wifi .

I need something like this ;

ADSL modem ----(share internet to) --> router ---WIFI---> HOTSPOT with Internet

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Make the modem and router into one network:

- Connect one of the Ethernet ports (LAN ports) of the modem to one of the Ethernet ports of the router (not to the WAN port).
- Modem: Disable the DHCP function and give it a static IP address within the
  router's network segment, example `192.168.1.251`.
- Router: Reduce the DHCP range so it doesn't overstep the modem,
  example `192.168.1.1-250`.

Comment: I've never utilized an ADSL modem, so this may not apply, but do they utilize the same RFC1918 IP that all cable modems are assigned (`192.168.1.100`)?  If so, wouldn't it be more convenient to simply change the router's DHCP subnet to anything other than `192.168.1.x/24` (i.e. `192.168.2.x/24`)?

Comment: @JW0914: No, everything must be on the same network.